# A summation with binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients

Evaluate

[image]

There seemed to be some problem with stackexchange's math rendering but Ian corrected whatever error was there in the expression.Thanks

$$5050 \frac {\left( \sum _{r=0}^{100} \frac {{100\choose r}}{50r+1}\cdot (-1)^r\right) - 1}{\left( \sum _{r=0}^{101}\frac{{101\choose r}}{50r+1} \cdot (-1)^r\right) - 1}$$

The original definite integral that led to this was

$$5050\frac{\int_0^1(1-x^{50})^{100} dx}{\int_0^1(1-x^{50})^{101} dx} $$

I used binomail to arrive at the above expression.

I already know a technique by definite integration but I want one by sequence and series.

> The answer is 5051

Comment: Pls don't downwote. I am using mobile so no preview available and I am trying to find error

Comment: Please see if I got the intended expression right.

Comment: Hello now the question is perfect please remove the downvotes

Answer (score 0):

**Use of sequence and series is not suggested; and a possible way is outlined, which is very long and useless, this is due to the fact of bounded multiplication of r with 50 in denominator, if the r would have been free, it would be easy to use this method to caluculate:**

### Brute Force

$$\frac{100\choose r}{50r+1}=1-50.\frac{r.{100\choose r}}{50r+1}$$
Use: $$r{100\choose r}=100.{99\choose{r-1}}$$
Then
$$\frac{{99\choose{r-1}}}{50r+1}=\left[1-50.\frac{r.{99\choose {r-1}}}{50r+1}\right]$$
Again use:
$$r{99\choose {r-1}}=99.{98\choose{r-2}}\text{ after }\frac{r.{99\choose {r-1}}}{50r+1}=\frac{(r-1).{99\choose {r-1}}}{50r+1}+\frac{{99\choose {r-1}}}{50r+1}$$
and so on...

---

The way you are mentioning- definite integration of $\beta$-function (though you may not be realising it is the $\beta$-function)- is the best method in my opinion.

---

You should use these(preferred but not necessary) while summing binomial coefficients:
$$r{n\choose r}=n{{n-1}\choose{r-1}};\frac1r{n\choose r}=\frac1{n+1}{{n+1}\choose{r+1}}$$
Secondly, use partial fractions or partial rationals.

Comment: Thank you. But I was thinking more of using $n\choose r = n\choose {r-1} + {n-1}\choose {r-1} $ in numerator and getting something to cut with the other

Comment: @MeghParikh See my edit for summation.

Answer (score -1):

This expression can be simplified using [Beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [Gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) functions. 
The sum in the numerator is
\begin{align}
\sum^{100}_{r=0}\binom{100}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{50r+1}
&=\sum^{100}_{r=0}\binom{100}{r}(-1)^r\int^1_0x^{50r}dx\\
&=\int^1_0(1-x^{50})^{100}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{50}\int^1_0u^{-49/50}(1-u)^{100}du\\
&=\frac{1}{50}B(1/50,101)\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(1/50) \ \Gamma(101)}{50 \ \Gamma(5051/50)}
\end{align}
Similarly, the sum in the denominator is
\begin{align}
\int^1_0(1-x^{50})^{101}dx
&=\frac{\Gamma(1/50) \ \Gamma(102)}{50 \ \Gamma(5101/50)}
\end{align}
Assuming you meant
$$5050\frac{\sum^{100}_{r=0}\binom{100}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{50r+1}}{\sum^{101}_{r=0}\binom{101}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{50r+1}}$$
instead, the above expression evaluates to
$$\frac{5050 \ \color\red{\Gamma(1/50)} \ \Gamma(101)}{\color\red{50} \ \Gamma(5051/50)}\frac{\color\red{50} \ \Gamma(5101/50)}{\color\red{\Gamma(1/50)} \ \Gamma(102)}=\frac{5050\cdot5051}{50\cdot 101}=5051$$

Comment: I don't want an integration technique.  I want a series and sequences technique. Plus I don't know beta and gamma functions.

Comment: @MeghParikh Unfortunately, using Beta integrals to compute this expression is the most viable method for me. Also, there might be a slight error in the expression above, the $-1$s in both numerator and denominator should not be there for the answer to be $5051$

Comment: My method was to use IBP in $I_{100}$ and taking 1 as the easily integrable function. We get relation betn $I100\ and I101$

Comment: Also if you use binomial then you have to put both limits 0 and 1.. Due to zero the -1 is left

Comment: @MeghParikh Note that $$\left[\sum^{100}_{r=0}\binom{100}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{50r+1}\right]-1=\sum^{100}_{r=1}\binom{100}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{50r+1}\neq\int^1_0(1-x^{50})^{100}dx$$. For the equality to hold, the sum must start from $r=0$ (equivalently, remove the $-1$ term.